# testing Guard with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard

I have a simple Ruby app that uses Guard to perform some actions when a file is copied into a folder, according to file extension.

I need to test with RSpec that the correct Guard Plugin is called when a file is copied, for instance if a `csv` file is copied the `CsvFile` plugin is called while if a `xls` file is copied the `XlsFile` plugin is called.

My Guardfile is very simple as follows:

```
 # require all Guard plugins

    guard :csv_file do
      watch(%r{^(.+)\.csv})
    end

    guard :xls_file do
      watch(%r{^(.+)\.xls})
    end
```

How may I use RSpec to do so?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Why do you want to test this with RSpec? Guard depends on other services like the file system. Even if the spec passes on your computer, it might not pass on another system. Besides that, Guard should already be tested. This is the sort of thing that I would not test...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, for compliance reasons I need to test it. As last step we run our specs on production environment.

Comment: Guard and RSpec don't run in a production environment.

Comment: Mine do. Thanks for your response